# Bot not responding discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Here is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = "MY TOKEN"
import random

intent = discord.Intents.default()
intent.members = True
intent.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intent)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='--', intents=discord.Intents.default())

slap_gif = ['https://media.tenor.com/GBShVmDnx9kAAAAC/anime-slap.gif', 'https://media.tenor.com/CvBTA0GyrogAAAAC/anime-slap.gif', 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/39/cf/fe39cfc3be04e3cbd7ffdcabb2e1837b.gif', 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/68/de/67/68de679cc20000570e8a7d9ed9218cd3.gif']

slap_txt = ['Ya, you deserve it', 'Get slapped', 'Ya, get slapped hard']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def slap(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=discord.Color("#ee5253"),
        description = f"{ctx.author.mention} {(random.choice(slap_txt))}"
    )

    embed.set_image(url=(random.choice(slap_gif)))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I am trying to create a basic gif action bot but it is not working, it was working with on_message but i switched to @bot.command and it is not working now. it runs with no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>`on_message` reacts on any text you send.
`@bot.command()` just reacts to the the command name with the prefix, which would be in your case `--slap`.</strike>

I just can guess, but eventually you didn't send the correct message text.

Because `discord.Bot` is a subclass of `discord.Client` you only need exactly one of the two (because you register the command `bot`, but you run `client`, the command registered on `bot` won't work. Also preferably you should keep the `discord.Bot` instance which is named `bot` because it as it is a subclass it has more functionality) and you should replace all occurrences of `client` with that.

Also your `bot` seems to have the wrong intents. If I change `bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=discord.Intents.default())` to `bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intent)` it ran the `slap` function (It has thrown an error for me, but that's not the topic of this question).

Comment: No, I sent the correct message (--slap)

Is it something with `await bot.process_commands(message)`?

Comment: I don't see this line anywhere in your example, do you still have a custom `on_message` floating around somewhere or where do you use `await bot.process_commands(message)`?

Comment: No I didn't use `await bot.process_commands(message)` and there is no `on_message` def